# Where does the word "log" in log pair come from?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, minimal-model-program, etymology

The minimal model program works with pairs $(X,B)$ where $X$ is a variety and $B$ is a certain kind of divisor on it. I've seen these described as "logarithmic pairs". There are also "log resolutions", "log canonical singularities" and so on.

> **Question:** What do these things have to do with logarithms?

Comment: It would help if you could clarify your background, the length of an answer would seriously depend on it.

Comment: I know some algebraic geometry on the level of Hartshorne. I don't know anything about log algebraic geometry, if that's what you're wondering. For what it's worth, I always favor longer and more detailed answers over shorter ones.

Comment: The general idea is that in log geometry goes around the idea of consider differential forms which aren't necessarily regular, bur have certain mild singularities, called logarithmic singularities, along $B$. The reason they are called so is because such forms are related to ones of the form $df/f$, which "morally" are just $d(\log f)$ (except we don't admit $\log f$ itself as a function, just this differential).

Comment: Indeed, one of the starting points is the fact that the cohomology of a complement of the normal crossing divisor can be computed via the sheaf of differential forms with logarithmic singularities along the divisor. This is discussed and used in a crucial way in Hodge II, Section 3.

Comment: [Grothendieck's letter to Atiyah](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1966__29__95_0.pdf) is more leisurely than Hodge II, 3.

Comment: @BenWieland that's a great paper for sure, but logarithmic differential forms do not appear there, instead he uses forms with poles of arbitrary order. As far as I know, it was really Deligne's idea that the logarithmic de Rham complex is quasi-isomorphic to that.

Comment: Oh, yeah, he seems to leave it to [Hodge-Atiyah](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007100), who use them in the proof of lemma 17, but don't quite globalize them.

Comment: Specializing to the case of MMP, why are log pairs the relevant thing to consider there?